# System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I tried multiple change in web.config to solve this issue getting during the deployment on 1&1 hosting provider.

[image]

any body knows the specific solution so i can try...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see issue in attachment.

Comment: Can you add you confg file?

Comment: Thanks, Actually i found cause of the issue and that can only be fixed at hosting provided side. Our application need "Full Trust" permission level for deployment and 1&1 providing "Medium Trust" permission level so we need to ask 1&1 for full trust permission level.